# Can I hide “All Synced Photographs” from the Lightroom sidebar?

Tags: lightroom

Lightroom Classic CC shows an All Synced Photographs collection in the Catalog list in Library mode. I don’t sync any photos with Adobe’s cloud offering so this collection is always empty. Is there a way to hide this collection from the Catalog list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, *no*. It is one of four permanent collections in the catalog panel, and they cannot be removed:

- All Photographs
- All Synced Photographs
- Quick Collection
- Previous Import

But you can, of course, hide the entire Catalog panel if you like, or use solo mode so it only opens when you are actively looking at one of its items. I find the inability to remove that collection aggravating, since I don't sync photos either, but ultimately it's a small issue and I've learned to live with it. We don't really have a choice, anyway.